# Python Module Error on Linux

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, linux-mint, spyder

I am using python 2.7 on Linux Mint 16. I am facing an error, if I run my IDE (tried it on Spyder and Pycharm) from a program launcher (eg. from the prompt at Alt F2 or an icon shortcut on my desktop) the modules do not load and I get the following error

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gurobipy/__init__.py", line 1, in 
    from .gurobipy import *
ImportError: libgurobi56.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, if I run the program from the command line the modules load correctly and the program runs fine. I have only one installation each of the IDEs. The sys.path output from the two instances are as follows:

sys.path output for Pycharm run from  shortcut:

```
/home/XXXXXX/bin/pycharm-community-3.1.3/helpers/pydev', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/home/XXXXXX/PycharmProjects/untitled8']
```

sys.path oyutput for Pycharm run from command line:

```
/home/XXXXXX/bin/pycharm-community-3.1.3/helpers/pydev', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/home/XXXXXX/PycharmProjects/untitled8']
```

The package gurobipy is in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Installation procedure followed for gurobi package:

1) Untarred the download to /opt/gurobi562/linux64

2) Added following lines to .bashrc

```
export GUROBI_HOME="/opt/gurobi562/linux64"

export PATH="${PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/bin"

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${GUROBI_HOME}/lib"
```

3) In /opt/gurobi562/linux64 ran python setup.py install this created the gurobipy folder in /usr/local/lib/python2.7

4) Added the following line to .bashrc

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-   packages/gurobipy"
```

Comment: have you added the necessary lines to your .bashrc file?

Comment: Yes
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gurobipy"

Comment: downloaded package and ran setup.py that was there in the download

Comment: where did you untar the files to?

Comment: Edited answer with installation procedure followed

Comment: the fact that it's saying `libgurobi56.so` isn't there, even though you're trying to just import girobipy, wouldmake me presume that it's looking at something like gurobipy.so, which is actualyl a symlink, and possible a broken link. Could you post the contents of the gurobipy folders(preferably with -l to show all the link details if there are any)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't set the path to the gurobipy.

Download then  untar to `/opt`.

```
cd to `/opt/gurobi562/linux64` and run `python setup.py install`
```

Add following to `~/.bashrc`.

```
   export GUROBI_HOME="/opt/gurobi562/linux64"
   export PATH="${PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/bin"
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/lib"
```

From bash type `source ~/.bashrc`

start ipython shell and try `from gurobipy import *`, it should work fine, the only error it will give is about not having a licence if you have not downloaded and installed one from [here](http://www.gurobi.com/download/licenses/current)

To set system wide access, first create

```
sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/gurobi_pi.conf
```

Then add

```
/opt/gurobi562/linux64/lib
```

and save the file.

Then enter

```
sudo ldconfig
```

to update the libs across the system.
You should have access to the shared libs in Pycharm.

Comment: I have tried this, it works fine from the python shell with or without the path to gurobipy. The problem is when the IDE is run from a shortcut

Comment: it runs in pycharm when you run pycharm from bash yes?

Comment: Yes, it runs when pycharm is run from bash

Comment: As a small comment - the folder /opt/gurobi562/linux64 may not exist for you if you download the newer version. replace the 562 with whatever version you untarred

Comment: This is great. What kind of black magic is it? everything I add to that folder will be updated or what?

Comment: Very helpful answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing different behaviour because your `.bashrc` is always loaded before you launch PyCharm (or other editors) from the terminal. The other shortcuts know nothing of your `.bashrc` and they should not. It seems that this module requires some very interesting configuration.

Your best bet to not have to use the terminal every time is to modify the shortcuts you're using (which is up to you to figure out) to set the proper environment variables. The most important of these variables is the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/gurobi562/linux64/lib:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-   packages/gurobipy"
```

Warning: the `dist-   packages` seems odd but I've copied it out of your question. If it doesn't work, it's up to you to figure out what the right directory name is.